# getattr() versus __dict__ lookup, which is faster?

Tags: python, performance, getattr, dynamic-attributes

I can dynamically look up object attribute values using `object.__dict__[some_key]` or `getattr(object, some_key)`. Which is faster or better, and why?

```
>>> class SomeObject:
...     pass
... 
>>> so = SomeObject()
>>> so.name = 'an_object'
>>> getattr(so,'name')
'an_object'
>>> so.__dict__['name']
'an_object'
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You are much better off using [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) instead of going directly to the [`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) structure.

Not because it's faster or slower, but because the official API works in *all* circumstances, including for classes that do *not* have a `__dict__` (when using [`__slots__`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots) for example), or when an object implements the [`__getattr__`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) or [`__getattribute__`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) hooks, or when the attribute in question is a [descriptor](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) (such as a [`property`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property)), or a class attribute.

If you want to know if any one python statement or technique is faster than another, use the [`timeit` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) to *measure* the difference:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> class Foo(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.bar = 'spam'
>>> timeit.timeit("getattr(foo, 'bar')", 'from __main__ import foo')
0.2125859260559082
>>> timeit.timeit("foo.__dict__['bar']", 'from __main__ import foo')
0.1328279972076416
```

You can see that directly accessing `__dict__` is faster, but `getattr()` does a lot more work.

Comment: `getattr` also respects the MRO and descriptors (common example: properties).