# Retrieving Values from Module by Name?

Tags: python, python-2.7, module

I'm attempting to read the following data from a separate .py file in a different directory, specifically: "assets.ovs.screen0".

Show here is the contents of assets.ovs.screen0.placement:

```
selection_Size = [600,110]
selection_Loc  = [1500-600,208]
selection_Mov  = [0,115]
```

At the base of the tree is a file, test.py, currently reading:

```
import assets.ovs.screen0.placement as placement

requiredVar = "select_"

print placement.select_Size
print eval("placement."+ requiredVar)
```

Assuming there is a safer/easier way of doing this, what would it be?

Comment: If i understand you correctly you want to get an attribute by name. Try
`val = getattr(obj, 'attr_name', default_value)`. Also see (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can i try this way:

```
param = ["selection_Size", "selection_Loc", "selection_Mov", "error"]
for par in param:
    print par, placement.__dict__.get(par, None)

    # this should work too
    # print par, getattr(placement, par, None)
```

Output:

```
selection_Size [600, 110]
selection_Loc [900, 208]
selection_Mov [0, 115]
error None
```

Comment: i think he should better use `getattr()` instead of the `__dict__.get()` lookup. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14084917/2972353)

Comment: Why wouldn't a module have a dict though? That answer was geared towards classes.

Comment: @kweb123 you are right, we can use class with __getattr__.

Comment: True, but think using the built-in should be prefered before using magic methods directly. Just not to devolop a bad habbit :)