# How to set a variable as an attribute?

Tags: python, attributes, pytorch

I'm getting error when trying to set variable as an atribute.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('--arch', action='store',
                dest='arch', default='alexnet',
                help='Store a simple value') 

args = parser.parse_args()

model = models.args.arch(pretrained=True)
```

I know `models.args.arch` prodocues an error but how syntax should looke like to set a variable as an attribute? I could do it with if statements but it would be lot's of code and I guess it's possible in 1 line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to access the internal dict to update:

```
model = models.__dict__[args.arch](pretrained=True)
```

or using `getattr`:

```
 getattr(models, args.arch)(pretrained=True)
```

Comment: `getattr` would be preferable. `getattr(models, args.arch)(pretrained=True)`.

Comment: @chepner - could you exaplain why? What's the difference?

Comment: @JakubBielan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084897/getattr-versus-dict-lookup-which-is-faster

Comment: In short, think of `__dict__` as an *implementation* detail of, not an *interface* to, the attributes of an object.